# Access education/work data from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently (4th of April) deprecated the [education](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/education-experience/) and [work](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/work-experience/) nodes on the user object in their graph api.

I am creating an app which requires a user's previous education and work experience. The only data I really need is name of the institution/place of work and dates that the person was there.

I can't see anywhere in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#4-4-2018) how to access education and work data now. Is it still possible to access that data and if so, how?

If it is not, do you know if support for getting this data is going to be re-added?

Comment: No there is no way to access it.

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2019, there's no way to retrieve that information.

There's no mention in the documentation or the changelog *why* the API was removed, but looking at the timeline it could indeed be related to the Cambridge Analytica scandal.

Answer (score -3):

This node is deprecated

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/education-experience/

> This node has been deprecated as of April 4, 2018 and will return no data. Please see the changelog for more information.
>
> Deprecated Permissions — The following permissions are deprecated: [...]
>   user_education_history

Comment: I know it's deprecated, this is not helpful to me in any way and does not answer the question either. Is it possible to somehow access the data or have they just blanket removed any possibility of accessing it?

Comment: Seems they removed it, because of the the cambridge analytica scandal.